# Regex capture full match between two XML tags with duplicates

Tags: java, regex

```
<Head>
            <Post>value</Post>
            <PstlAdr>
                        <Ctry>…</Ctry>
                        <AdrLine>line1</AdrLine>
                        <AdrLine>line2</AdrLine>
                        <AdrLine>line3</AdrLine>
                        <AdrLine>line4</AdrLine>
            </PstlAdr>
</Head>
```

I want to capture all the text between the FIRST AdrLine tag and the LAST /AdrLine tag.

which means the captured group will contain:

```
                <AdrLine>line1</AdrLine>
                <AdrLine>line2</AdrLine>
                <AdrLine>line3</AdrLine>
                <AdrLine>line4</AdrLine>
```

Comment: You should use an XML parser.

Comment: Thanks but I prefer the Regex solution in this case

Comment: Finnally! Finally I can link [my favorite answer of all times](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/3316645).

Comment: @domdom I prefer this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/701166/can-you-provide-some-examples-of-why-it-is-hard-to-parse-xml-and-html-with-a-reg

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: TH̘Ë͖́̉ ͠P̯͍̭O̚​N̐Y̡ H̸̡̪̯ͨ͊̽̅̾̎Ȩ̬̩̾͛ͪ̈́̀́͘ ̶̧̨̱̹̭̯ͧ̾ͬC̷̙̲̝͖ͭ̏ͥͮ͟Oͮ͏̮̪̝͍M̲̖͊̒ͪͩͬ̚̚͜Ȇ̴̟̟͙̞ͩ͌͝S̨̥̫͎̭ͯ̿̔̀ͅ!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

XML is **not** a [Regular Language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_language) and hence cannot be parsed by *regular* expressions (unless you are using a known subset of XML which you may be able to parse with regexes). Use an XML parser instead.

Answer (score 1):

I totaly agreed that RegExp is not the best solution for parsing XML files.

But if you wish, and completely sure in your data format, use this:

`#(?:<AdrLine>.+?</AdrLine>\s*)+#`

RegExp101 Demo: https://regex101.com/r/hoikwl/1

Comment: I sure hope the file doesn’t have `<!-- <AdrLine>testValue</AdrLine> -->` at the end.

Comment: As i wrote, he must be `completely sure in data format`

Answer (score 0):

By definition, regular expressions don't allow recursion. (Constructs that allow recursion are referred to as - or equivalent to - [pushdown automata](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pushdown_automaton); an example is a [context-free grammar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-free_grammar)).

Since HTML and XML have a recursive structure, a Regex can't be used to parse HTML in the general case.

If you're acting on a very restricted structure, though, you *could* try to match all of the `<AdrLine>` tags and just pull out the first and last matches in Java. You'd have to have a very strict structure, though.